Failed building wheel for pendulum when pip installing Microsoft Graph SDK
pip install msgraph-sdk gives an error relating to an arithmetic operation inside src\helpers.rs:59:20
  error: this arithmetic operation will overflow
    --> src\helpers.rs:59:20
     |
  59 |         seconds += ((146_097 - 10957) * SECS_PER_DAY as usize) as isize;
     |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `135140_usize * 86400_usize`, which would overflow
     |
     = note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default
 
  error: could not compile `_pendulum` (lib) due to 1 previous error
  ðŸ’¥ maturin failed
    Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pendulum
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pendulum, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I cannot locate this Rust package file.

Could you please report the issue here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues ?

@user2250152 it is not a msgraph issue, but is in the pendulum library, a dependency. The issue should be reported there: https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues#
